# ASP.NET MVC Routing doesn't work with a prefix "api"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I'm new to the mvc, here I'm trying to add the **api** prefix in the URL pattern followed by controller, action and id.

But things does not work as I expected.

I have a controller named **"Activity"**,
with a method **"Query"**

```
public class ActivityController : Controller
{
    ...

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Query(int limit = DEFAULT_LIMIT,
        int offset = DEFAULT_OFFSET)
    {
        repository.apiInfo.data = repository.readActivities(limit, offset);

        return Json(repository.apiInfo , 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    ...
}
```

And I define a route mapping rule to try to invoke Query(), like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MyRule",
        url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Activity", action = "Query", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I've made sure it's registered at the **Application_Start()** method,
as well as it works well without the api prefix.

But it turns out to show the message

"Cannot find the url 'http://localhost:49571/api'"
"Cannot find the **Activity** controller."

Please tell me where did I miss out.

Comment: Do you register the `WebApi Controller` ? that might already take the prefix `api`

Comment: Api Controller can work, but I'm not familiar with it, so the way I need is working in the MVC routing, and I cannot understand why it doesn't work as the way I learnt from MVC routing.

Comment: WebApi routing run before MVC routing ,  when you url  `/api` come in , the webApi' hander will process this request (in this case it is status 404,but it also a result from the hander), MVC's routing will never be invoke , but you can take another prefix to work with MVC's routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably already have Web API enabled, whose routes are registered before MVC route. That means that any calls prefixed with `api` is being routed to your web api as first match wins in the route table.

Look for the following class in the project

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Note the `DefaultApi` route.

Either remove the above route or change the route being used by the MVC route collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
public class ActivityController : ApiController
```

Comment: Api Controller can work, but I'm not familiar with it, so the way I need is working in the MVC routing, and I cannot understand why it doesn't work as the way I learnt from MVC routing.